# How does throughput get impacted considering stop and wait protocol?

Tags: networking, tcp

How does the throughput get effected if we consider stop and wait protocol. I am assuming that stop and wait will add its own delay for transmitting data. Is there a mathematical equation for the same ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is  about general networking technology, not programming.


Comment: But its certainly conceptual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data throughput on any type of protocol that sends a stop and/or wait will be impacted by latency, as a delay is introduced between data blocks. This impacts protocols that use small block sizes significantly, but also affects windowed protocols like TCP.

Ultimately, the more packets that need to be sent back and forth between server and host between data blocks, and the smaller the blocks of data, the more throughput will suffer.

For example, TFTP sends data in fixed 512 byte blocks and requires 6 packets (3 from each side) to be exchanged before another block can be sent. Thus, on a connection where a ping (which is a round-trip) is 10 ms, figure there is a minimum 30 ms delay between sending blocks. That would mean that 33 blocks of 512 bytes of data could be delivered in a second, making max throughput approximately 17KBps (136 Kbps) assuming unlimited bandwidth and not counting any loss or other overhead.

Now consider a scenario where ping times are 50ms, thus 150ms of wait time occurs between transfer of blocks, 6.66 blocks per second of 512 bytes is equivalent to 3.4 KBps, or 27.3 Kbps is the maximum theoretical throughput, again regardless of bandwidth and other factors.

The formula used here was Theoretical Max Throughput = 1 second / delay between blocks * block size.

A good read on the subject as it relates to TCP is below.

http://bradhedlund.com/2008/12/19/how-to-calculate-tcp-throughput-for-long-distance-links/

Another good illustration of the way throughput degrades with the use of chatty protocols across WAN links is SMB aka Samba aka CIFS aka Windows File Transfer. It's a common problem in VPN environments using older Windows networks.

Answer (score 0):

The 'mathematical equation' is 'delay = delay + wait_time'. I'd call it grade 3 arithmetic myself.